# Edge of a curve based out of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, filtering, smoothing, derivative

I am looking for some mathematical guidance, to help me find the index locations (red circles) of a curve as shown in the image below. The curve is just 1D numpy array. I tried scipy - `gaussianfilter1d`. I also tried `np.gradient` and I am not anywhere close to what I want to do. The gradient is abruptly changing, so a first order gradient should give what I am looking for. Then I realized the data is not smooth, and I tried smoothing by 'gaussianfilter1d'. Even then, I am unable to pick up where it changes. I have various types of these numpy arrays (same size, values ranging from 0 - 1), so the solution has to be applicable, and not dependent on the given data set. So I could not hardcode. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

[CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tmyn3KYR2_E1gxmWqAfY5CBNdlQXBoMg/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe add a couple more CSVs please?

Comment: my approach would be: 1) filter data to smooth curve 2) find the index x for which the circle through the points (x-y), x, (x+y) has the smalles radius (for ex y=400) - this with the center above the point in x and in the first halve and second halve seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get a smooth function from your data using `scipy's` `UnivariateSpline`. Then you plot the area where the absolute slope is say at least 1/4 of it's maximum.

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

f= UnivariateSpline(np.arange(5500), y, k=3, s=0.3)
df = f.derivative()
plt.plot(x,f(x))
cond = np.abs(df(x)) > 0.25*np.max(np.abs(df(x)))
plt.scatter(x[cond],f(x[cond]), c='r')
```

[image: function with high slope marked]
Looks like what you are looking for is the first and last point of the marked ones. So you do

```
(x[cond].min(),f(x[cond].min()).item()), (x[cond].max(), f(x[cond].max()).item())
```

And your points are:

```
((1455, 0.20595740349084446), (4230, 0.1722999962943679))
```